# Pygame Flickering Sprite

Tags: python, pygame

Everything in the game works fine so far except the sprite flickers when it moves. The sprite has a trail of its last location behind it. I only have one *pygame.display.update()* and no *pygame.display.flip()*, I say that because of the answers I got when I looked up the problem saying that may cause the issue. I use *pygame.sprite.Group.draw()* and *pygame.sprite.Group.clear()* methods from my derived group class.
Here is a link https://youtu.be/Ayzy5prix84 to a demonstration. Thank you for your help in advance.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()


class Game():
    def __init__(self, name = "", width=600, height=400):
        self.name = name
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.window = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
        pygame.display.set_caption(self.name)
        self.scenarios = {}
        self.active_scenario = None
    def update(self):
        self.scenarios[self.active_scenario].update(self.window)
    def draw(self):
        if self.scenarios != None:
            self.scenarios[self.active_scenario].draw(self.window)
    def add_scene(self, name, obj):
        if self.active_scenario == None:
            self.active_scenario = name
        self.scenarios[name] = obj

class Scenario:
    def __init__(self, background, menus = None, sprite_groups = None):
        self.background = background
        self.menus = menus
        self.sprite_groups = sprite_groups
        self.boundaries = self._set_boundaries()
    def _set_boundaries(self):
        boundaries = {}
        rect = self.background.image.get_rect()
        left = rect.left
        right = rect.right

        left_bound = Boundary((left,0, 1, rect.h))
        right_bound = Boundary((rect.w - 1,0, 1, rect.h))
        top_bound = Boundary((left,0, rect.w, 1))
        bottom_bound = Boundary((left,rect.h - 1, rect.w, 1))

        boundaries["left bound"] = left_bound
        boundaries["right bound"] = right_bound
        boundaries["top bound"] = top_bound
        boundaries["bottom bound"] = bottom_bound


        return boundaries
    def check_collision(self):
        for group in self.sprite_groups:
            for sprite in group.sprites():
                if sprite.rect.left < self.boundaries["left bound"].right:
                    sprite.rect.x = self.boundaries["left bound"].right 
                if sprite.rect.top < self.boundaries["top bound"].bottom:
                    sprite.rect.y = self.boundaries["top bound"].bottom
                if sprite.rect.right > self.boundaries["right bound"].left:
                    sprite.rect.x = self.boundaries["right bound"].left - sprite.rect.w
                if sprite.rect.bottom > self.boundaries["bottom bound"].top:
                    sprite.rect.y = self.boundaries["bottom bound"].top - sprite.rect.h
    def update_char(self):
        global key_dict
        #just finds the character sprite will change later this is a test of mechanics
        sprites = self.sprite_groups[0].sprites()
        character = sprites[0]


        if key_dict["up"] and not key_dict["down"]:
            character.rect.y -= character.speed
        if key_dict["down"] and not key_dict["up"]:
            character.rect.y += character.speed
        if key_dict["left"] and not key_dict["right"]:
            character.rect.x  -= character.speed
        if key_dict["right"] and not key_dict["left"]:
            character.rect.x  += character.speed



    def update(self, screen):
        self.update_char()
        self.check_collision()
        self.draw(screen)
    #draws the scenario to a surface then blit surface to main window named
    #screen
    def draw(self, screen):
        size = screen.get_size()
        surface = pygame.Surface((size[0], size[1]))
        self.background.draw(surface)
        if self.sprite_groups != None:
            for group in self.sprite_groups:
                group.clear(surface, self.background.image)
                group.draw(surface)
        screen.blit(surface, (0,0))


class Group(pygame.sprite.Group):
    def __init__(self, *sprites):
        pygame.sprite.Group.__init__(self, sprites)

class Sprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image, *groups):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, groups)
        self.image = pygame.image.load(image)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.left = self.rect.left
        self.right = self.rect.right
        self.top = self.rect.top
        self.bottom = self.rect.bottom

class Background:
    def __init__(self, image=None):
        self.image = pygame.image.load(image)
    def draw(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.image, (0,0))


class Wall(Sprite):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        Sprite.__init__(self, args)

class Boundary:
    def __init__(self, rect, active=True):
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(rect)
        self.left = self.rect.left
        self.right = self.rect.right
        self.top = self.rect.top
        self.bottom = self.rect.bottom
        self.active = active

key_dict = {"left":False, "right":False, "up":False, "down":False}

game = Game("Key Finder")

ball = Sprite("../Sprites/Ball/Static.png")
ball.speed = 5
char_g = Group(ball)

sky = Background("Sky.png")
scene = Scenario(sky, sprite_groups = [char_g])
game.add_scene("Level 1", scene)


FPS = 60
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
running = True

while running:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                key_dict["up"] = True
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                key_dict["down"] = True
            elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                key_dict["left"] = True
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                key_dict["right"] = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                key_dict["up"] = False
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                key_dict["down"] = False
            elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                key_dict["left"] = False
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                key_dict["right"] = False

    game.update()
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(FPS)

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

You over complicated the redrawing of the scene, that may cause the flickering:

> ```
> class Scenario: 
>    # [...]
>    def draw(self, screen):
>        size = screen.get_size()
>        surface = pygame.Surface((size[0], size[1]))
>        self.background.draw(surface)
>        if self.sprite_groups != None:
>            for group in self.sprite_groups:
>                group.clear(surface, self.background.image)
>                group.draw(surface)
>        screen.blit(surface, (0,0))
> ```

Generating a surface with the size of the game window (`surface = pygame.Surface((size[0], size[1]))`), in every frame is a waist of time. Actually you create a surface with the size of the window, draw to that surface and copy the surface to the window. That causes a massive performance loss.
Draw to the surface which is associated to window directly. Note, you won't see the changes to the window surface directly. The changes are flushed once, when `pygame.display.update()` or `pygame.display.flip()` is invoked.
Since the entire scene is drawn in every frame, `group.clear(surface, self.background.image)` is superfluous as well. Note, the back ground covers the entire window, then the objects of the scene are drawn on top of the background.

Simplify the `draw` (in `Scenario`), to solve the issue.

```py
class Scenario:
    # [...]

    def draw(self, screen):
        self.background.draw(screen)
        if self.sprite_groups != None:
            for group in self.sprite_groups:
                group.draw(screen)
```

If the `background` doesn't cover the entire window, then you have to clear the window before `self.background.draw(screen)`, by `screen.fill(0)`

Comment: Thank you for your help with the performance issues and for taking time to answer. My problem, however, did not resolve with the solution suggested. Again thank you for your time and advice.